# How to catch a Cox model fitting poorly?

Tags: r, cox-model, fitting

I am doing some Cox modelizations in R and some of the models don't fit.

Since I am mostly doing routines with function, I would like to be able to catch the case when my model doesn't fit.

Here are my attempts :

```
#My variable which doesn't fit
> cox.ko=coxph(os~bad.var, data=db)
Warning message:
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Loglik converged before variable  1,2 ; beta may be infinite. 
> cox.ko %>% summary
Call:
coxph(formula = os~bad.var, data = db)

  n= 302, number of events= 36 
   (134 observations deleted due to missingness)

                 coef      exp(coef)  se(coef)     z    Pr(>|z|)
bad.var15-30 min 1.581e+01 7.321e+06 4.760e+03 0.003    0.997
bad.var>=30 min  1.604e+01 9.271e+06 4.760e+03 0.003    0.997

                  exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
bad.var15-30 min   7320785  1.366e-07         0       Inf
bad.var>=30 min    9270707  1.079e-07         0       Inf

Concordance= 0.514  (se = 0.025 )
Rsquare= 0.003   (max possible= 0.72 )
Likelihood ratio test= 0.91  on 2 df,   p=0.634
Wald test            = 0.11  on 2 df,   p=0.9488
Score (logrank) test = 0.51  on 2 df,   p=0.7752

#My variable which fit
> cox.ok=coxph(os~good.var, data=db)
> cox.ok %>% summary
Call:
coxph(formula = os~good.var, data = db)

  n= 418, number of events= 71 
   (18 observations deleted due to missingness)

                 coef     exp(coef) se(coef)  z      Pr(>|z|)
good.var]25;30]  0.1411    1.1515   0.2598  0.543    0.587
good.var>30     -0.1099    0.8959   0.3487 -0.315    0.753

                   exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
good.var]25;30]    1.1515     0.8684    0.6920     1.916
good.var>30        0.8959     1.1161    0.4523     1.775

Concordance= 0.522  (se = 0.034 )
Rsquare= 0.001   (max possible= 0.851 )
Likelihood ratio test= 0.58  on 2 df,   p=0.7497
Wald test            = 0.57  on 2 df,   p=0.7502
Score (logrank) test = 0.58  on 2 df,   p=0.7495

#number of iterations : 
> cox.ko$iter
[1] 16
> cox.ok$iter
[1] 3
```

As you can see, my first model doesn't fit, as per the 16 iterations, the nearly infinite betas (e+06) and the confidence interval.

The documentation of survival package says that [default maximum iteration is 20](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/coxph.control.html), so it seems that there are more than that to say it fitted.

**Just to prevent the "you could just..."**, I know I could test that the upper confindence interval is `Inf` or that `exp(coef)` is not more than 100, but it would look mostly like a workaround and not a "neat" solution. I know I also could tryCatch() it and catch the warning, but as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19370173/3888000), "the test that is being triggered to generate that warning is overly sensitive", so it would generate too many false positives.

I know R quite a bit, but my understanding of theoretical statistics behind the Cox model is not good enough to figure it out.

**THIS IS NOT A PROGRAMMING QUESTION**. I just need to know what make sense to test because iterations are apparently not enough. You don't have to explain how to test it programmatically, I can go to Stack Overflow if I cannot do it myself.

What is the recommended way to test if my model fit well?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: As I saw on meta, the right site to post is the site where expert are. I don't need an expert in R or in programming now, I need an expert in statistics

Comment: As it stands, this looks like it should be closed to me. If you can rewrite this in software neutral terms, it should be on-topic. This looks like you want help w/ the code.

Comment: @gung Is this better ? I still have to show my R attempts and outputs, don't I ?